# Getting to know if '*' is included in a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable and I want to know if the multiplication symbol is in the string. This is what I did:

```
const str = "45*33"
const arr = str.split('')
if(arr.includes("*"){
console.log("Symbol found!")
}
else{
console.log("Error")
})
```

This does not work, is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Also you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split at all; you can directly use `String#includes`.

```
const str = "45*33";
if (str.includes("*")) {
    console.log("Symbol found!")
} else {
    console.log("Error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the console of your browser to check for errors.
It is a simple syntax error at:

```
if(arr.includes("*"){
```

should be:

```
if(arr.includes("*")){
```

Answer (score 0):

Working perfectly now, it was a typo in the code that my eye just did not see. There is a reason why I had to split the string to an array. I could have just used the str.includes().

```
const str = "45*33"
const arr = str.split('')
if(arr.includes("*")){
console.log("Symbol found!")
}
else{
console.log("Error")
})
```

Thank you.